# ASP.NET - Cron job with password protected page

Tags: asp.net, web-config, cron, password-protection

I am trying to read an xml-feed into a database on a specific time with cron jobs. Everything is working fine (the cron job calls the page and the xml-script starts running and reading into the database) except that i dont want someone else to be able to run the script by visiting this page. Therefore I have been looking at setting up a password-protected page for this script, but there is not a lot of information about how to do this with cron jobs and asp.net.

It seems to be so much easier with php (use the htaccess-file and send the username and password with the cron-job url like http://username:password@yoursite.com/cron).
Is it possible to do this with asp.net sites?

I have to use cron job since my web hosting provider don't have windows task scheduler.

Thanks,
Axel

Answer (score 0):

you could use pass protected url in dir specific web.config

Answer (score 0):

Two points come to my mind

1. http://username:password@yoursite.com/cron like url is useless for securing if https is not used. You can make you asp.net url equivalent to it using query string.
2. If ssl is not possible why dont you enable ip checking that the code will only run when the page is requested from a specific ip(Linux server ip)??

Comment: I think i will go for the ip-checking solution! Thanks a lot for that information! Sometimes its hard to be creative and come up with simple ideas like checking the ip :)